# Incompaitible types: Dog(Cat) can not be converted to Animal

Tags: java

Здравствуйте!
Ошибка в конце кода а точнее в двух местах:
list.add(a);
list.add(c); 
В классе MyAnimalList имеется метод add! 
Но в классе AnimalTestDrive предлагается либо создать уже созданный метод 
add иначе ругается - " Dog(Cat) can not be converted to Anmal"
Почему игнорируется мой метод add?

```
public class MyAnimalList {

 private Animal[] animals = new Animal[5];
 private int nextIndex = 0;

  public void add(Animal a) {
    if (nextIndex < animals.length) {
        animals[nextIndex] = a;
        System.out.println("Animal добавляем в ячейку " + nextIndex);
        nextIndex++;

}

}

}

public class AnimalTestDrive {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyAnimalList list = new MyAnimalList();
        Dog a = new Dog();
        Cat c = new Cat();

        list.add(a);
        list.add(c);


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Dog extends Animal {
  ...
}
public class Cat extends Animal {
  ...
}
```

Суть проблемы в том, что Ваши `Dog` и `Cat` не являются `Animal`. Если Вы унаследуете эти классы от `Animal`, то объекты этих типов можно будет использовать в коде, который ожидает тип `Animal`.

Comment: Спасибо конечно! но мне бы понять суть проблемы(